# Suppose given that $ \lim_{x \to 0}f(x)=1 \lim_{x \to 0}g(x)=\infty \lim_{x \to 0}g(x)(f(x)-1)=c $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Suppose given that

$$ \lim_{x \to 0}f(x)=1 \\ \lim_{x \to 0}g(x)=\infty \\ \lim_{x \to 0}g(x)(f(x)-1)=c  $$

Then find the value of $ \lim_{x \to 0} f(x)^{g(x)} $

So this is what I've done. Please verify if its correct approach @Macavity
$$ f(x)^{g(x)} =  e^{\log{f(x)^{g(x)}}} = e^{{g(x)\log f(x)}}  $$  $(1)$

Now from Taylor series expansion of $\log(1+x)$ Substitute $x$ by $f(x)-1 $ in the Taylor series
$$\log f(x)=  (f(x)-1) - \frac12(f(x)-1)^2 \cdots$$    $(2)$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$ By taking only the first term of the $\log f(x) $ expansion

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} f(x)^{g(x)}= e^c  $$

Is this approach correct?

Comment: your answer is correct.

Comment: @BRIC-Fan is my Taylor substitution valid? Because by putting $f(x)-1 $ as $x$ in $\log(1+x) $ I have doubt regarding the value of $x$ as it should be always positive. And $f(x)-1$ is negative. So is the substitution valid???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is intuitively correct. But a simpler approach with rigorous justification of all the steps is as follows.

Let $L = \lim_{x \to 0}f(x)^{g(x)}$ so that
\begin{align}\log L &= \log\left(\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)^{g(x)}\right)\notag\\
&=\lim_{x \to 0}\log f(x)^{g(x)}\text{ (by continuity of log)}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}g(x)\log f(x)\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}g(x)\log \{1 + f(x) - 1\}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}g(x)(f(x) - 1)\dfrac{\log \{1 + f(x) - 1\}}{f(x) - 1}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}g(x)(f(x) - 1)\cdot\lim_{t \to 0}\dfrac{\log (1 + t)}{t}\text{ (by putting }t = f(x) - 1)\notag\\
&= c\cdot 1 = c\end{align} and hence $L = e^{c}$. We have used the standard limit $$\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{\log(1 + t)}{t} = 1$$ Also note that the second condition $\lim_{x \to 0}g(x) = \infty$ is unnecessary as can be seen in the above derivation.

Comment: Thank You         @Paramanand Singh

Comment: @Paramanand. I think it is necessary to prove first that the limit L exists and is positive and not equal to zero and not equal to + infinity in order to starts the your proof. Otherwise one cannot take its logarithm. Maybe for this purpose one make use of the condition $\lim_{x \to 0}g(x)= \infty $.

Comment: @Paramanand. There are three hypothesis, one on $f$, the second on $g$ and the third on $f$ and $g$ together. So, it is impossible to have the first one and the third one if for example the limit of g is finite unless $c=0$. So, if the limit of $g$ do not exists at all and the limit of $L$ exists as a positive real number then the result still holds. (according to your proof). It remains to see whether $L$ exists and where it is. (Open question).

Comment: @Idris: Note the following general result *if $f(x)$ is positive in a neighborhood of point $a$ and $\log f(x) \to L$ as $x \to a$ then $f(x) \to e^{L}$ as $x \to a$." In simpler terms if limit of $\log f(x)$ exists then limit of $f(x)$ also exists (converse is also true). Hence logs can be taken without knowing beforehand whether the limit exists or not. In fact any one-one continuous function can be applied on a limit expression without knowing its existence before hand.

Comment: @Idris: I should say that second condition is redundant. First and third conditions are enough to get the result. Also $c$ may be zero.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh – Thank you.